# send message to specific clients using java

Tags: java

How can i send message from server to any specific client. I have the concept of how to do it like i have to make a list of all the clients connected to server and then by iterating each client i can send message but i will be thankful if any one can help me by code.I have searched many codes but i didn't get any considerable help from them Code shouldn't be GUI based. Thanks in advance.Sorry for my bad English.
This is my code in which message is send to all clients but i want to send message to a client of my choice using clients ipaddress

```
Map<Integer, java.net.Socket> clients = new HashMap<Integer, java.net.Socket> ();
socket = serverSocket.accept();

// Add the socket to a HashMap
clients.put(socket.getPort(), socket);
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = clients.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
{
    int key = iter.next();

    java.net.Socket client = clients.get(key);

    // Sending the response back to the client.
    // Note: Ideally you want all these in a try/catch/finally block
    OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    bw.write("Some message");
    bw.flush();
}
```

Comment: I just saw you added this as a separate question. It depends on how you want to identify the client that you want to single out. Do you know how you want to do so?

Comment: Yes Sir as soon as client connected to server it sends his ipadress and username to the server and now using ipadressess i want to send a message to any specific client one option i have is that if i want to send the message to client of ipaddress 192.168.1.1 then i ll send the message and the ipaddress to all clients and then simply apply check on client side that which client has that ipadress and if any one ofthem have that ipadress display that mesage to him

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is create a Client class:

```
class Client
{
   private String userName;
   private String ipAddress;
   private java.net.Socket socket = null;

   public Client (String userName, String ipAddress, java.net.Socket socket)
   {
      this.userName = userName;
      this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
      this.socket = socket;
   }

   public java.net.Socket getSocket()
   {
       return this.socket;
   }
}
```

Instead of adding just the socket and port number to the map, I would map the combination of the userName and ipAddres to a Client object.

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();

// get the username from the socket
// get the ipAddress from the socket
Client c = new Client(userName, ipAddress, socket);

// Add the client to a HashMap
clients.put(userName + ":" + ipAddress, c);
```

Now, you can send a message to a specific client based on the username and ipAddress:

```
public void sendToOneClient (String userName, String ipAddress, Map<String, Client> clients)
{
    Client c = clients.get(userName + ":" + ipAddress);

    java.net.Socket socket = c.getSocket();

    // Sending the response back to the client.
    // Note: Ideally you want all these in a try/catch/finally block
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    bw.write("Some message");
    bw.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Socket.getInetAddress()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress()) and compare the result to whatever you have the IPs you want to send to in. Personally, I'd use a `String[]` or `ArrayList<String>` for that. Here's an example:

```
ArrayList<String> addresses;
//TODO: Add things to 'addresses'

clients.put(socket.getPort(), socket);
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = clients.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
{
    int key = iter.next();

    java.net.Socket client = clients.get(key);

    //Checking to make sure it's a client we want to send to.
    if (addresses.contains(client.getInetAddress().toString()) {
        // Sending the response back to the client.
        // Note: Ideally you want all these in a try/catch/finally block
        OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        bw.write("Some message");
        bw.flush();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could store the sockets in your HashMap by the InetAddress instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a relationship between how you want to look up the client with the socket that they are on. The natural way to do this is with a map, like

```
Map<String, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<String,Socket>();
...
ServerSocket ss = ...;
Socket s = ss.accept();
String username = getUserName(s);
sockets.put(username, s);
```

Obviously, in this example here, the client would have to send his/her userName in a format which you expect to receive after making the Socket connection

Comment: I think it should be sockets.put(userID,s)  @ControlAltDel

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is effective to create an object type that can hold both a unique name or id be it an `int` or a `String` and also a `Socket`. You could store instances of this object in an `ArrayList` (or any other list) and iterate through them searching for the name or id that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for my program.Here I used the ">>" string to specify that a message should be sent to a particular user. *(e.g.: "Ross>>Hi Ross What's Up?" means that the message should be sent to the user named 'Ross')*. I used a HashMap(named 'WritersMap') to keep details as KEY-VALUE pairs. Key will be the name of the user who sends the particular message and Value will be that message. 'in' is a BufferedReader instance.

```
while (true) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    if (input == null) //if there is no input,do nothing
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    //when a user sends a message to a specific user
                    else if(input.contains(">>"))   //checks whether the message contains a >> 
                    {
                        String person=input.substring(0,input.indexOf(">"));    //extract the name of the destination user 
                        for(HashMap.Entry<String,PrintWriter> entry:writersMap.entrySet())  //find the destination user from the users list 
                        {
                            if(entry.getKey().matches(person))  //if the destination user is found 
                            {
                                PrintWriter writer=entry.getValue();
                                writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else    //when a user sends a broadcast message to all users 
                    { 

                        for(HashMap.Entry<String,PrintWriter> entry:writersMap.entrySet())  //find the destination user from the users list 
                        {
                            PrintWriter writer=entry.getValue();
                            writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                        }
                    }
                }
```